# How do I solve for $dy/dx$ if $y=\ln (\sin x+\ln x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=\ln(\sin x+\ln x)$.

I know how to solve for integrals involving $du$ and $u$, but how do I do this type of problem (I think it's the opposite of the integral problem)?

Comment: @5space Thanks for the edit. I still don't know how to write mathematical equations here in math.stackexchange..

Comment: check this link out: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

As well, you may like to look at a quick start guide to LaTeX.

Comment: Oh, so it's LaTeX formatting? I've tried LaTeX before, but I didn't know LaTeX applies here, or anywhere outside of LaTeX editors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "good old" ***[chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)***: remember that?

$$y = \ln(f(x)) \iff y' = \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

$$y = \ln(\sin x + \ln x) \implies y' = \dfrac{\left(\cos x + \frac 1x\right)}{\sin x + \ln x}$$

Comment: I doubt myself so much that this was my answer when I solved the problem earlier, but I wasn't too confident about it. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @amWhy: still can't shut down I see! :-) =1

Comment: I completely understand "self-doubt" or "second-guessing"; I've been there!

Comment: Hearing that from someone who reaps 200+ reputation here a day, I am inclined to doubt that :p Haha!

Answer (score 3):

You use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), which says $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$